# Timeout implementation for sql stored procedure and C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement timeout functionality for database stored procedure.
This timeout value will be fetched from app.config.

I am processing thousand of records using stored procedure. When I call my master procedure in again calls some more store procedures inside. Everything has been wrapped using C# transactionScope. 
I have a list in C# which will fetch single record for processing and hits master stored procedure.

I want to stop this processing as soon as timeout value matches. I mean if timeout is 20 then my processing should be executed for 20 seconds and it should stop processing after 20 seconds.

I tried using `adoCommand.CommandTimeout`property but unfortunately its not stopping at all.

Please help.

Comment: Given that the problem seems isolated to the expected behavior of `CommandTimeout`, can you post the relevant code including creation of the command, setting the `CommandTimeout` property, and executing the command? While it's imaginable that there's some undocumented behavior, it's way more likely that it's not being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to tell what has gone wrong without looking at the code.

From the documentation on [CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).
>
> The CommandTimeout property will be ignored during asynchronous method calls such as BeginExecuteReader.
>
> CommandTimeout has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string).